# Annoying issue with yaml which I cannot overcome

Tags: linux, kubernetes, cloud, devops

I keep getting

> error: error parsing httpd-project-last.yaml.backup1: error converting
>   YAML to JSON: yaml: line 45: did not find expected key

. 
So the line is the one with
**key: password**
I don't know what to do. Pulling my hair for an hour now I keep getting it.
Any tips?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webandstorage
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpd
        image: httpd:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc1
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      dnsConfig:
       nameservers:
         - 8.8.8.8
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data3
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: data
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: dbparola
       ports:
       - protocol: TCP
         port:8080
```

Comment: There are lot of errors. env should come under containers and not volumes, deployment should have one spec not two, there should be a space after :, so port:8080 is not valid.

Comment: Would suggest to try something small and then try this incrementally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the community pointed out, there are some errors in your yaml file. I've fixed the syntax, so it passes a validation test.

In case you will have issues with the configuration, you can always ask another question.

`apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webandstorage
spec:
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpd
        image: httpd:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc1
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      dnsConfig:
       nameservers:
         - 8.8.8.8
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data3
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: data
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: dbparola
        ports:
         - protocol: TCP
             port:8080`

You can check it on any YAML validator online, for [example](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cbcf4202), you can find your yaml here as I left it there as a static link for you.

You can find more information on how to create yaml files in this [article](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/introduction-to-yaml-creating-a-kubernetes-deployment/) or directly in the Kubernetes documentation for [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with your configuration. For example: there should be one containers section, and one volumes section. Each container would have a volumeMount specified.

Start by stripping down your definition to just one container, with volumeMounts and volumes, and then think about adding in the second container (but keeping one containers section! Look up yaml lists).